# Update text box from drop down box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate a total price based on what I select in a drop down menu; the product price can remain the same.

The code doesn't work for me for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/jscript">

$('#quantity').change(function(){
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  var price = $('#productPrice').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  $("#totalprice").val(total);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="pricesection">
    <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340"/>
Quantity: 
<select id="quantity">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
Total: $
<input type="text" id="totalprice" value="340"/>


</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you have convert the value of drop for execute the multiply!

Comment: sorry i dont understand, can you show me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there a wrong result? Is there no result at all? Any error from console? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have reworded your question, but you (and only you) can substantially improve this by explaining what you expect to happen and what happens instead. "Not working" doesn't give anybody a clue what they should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The values from the select drop down and the input field you retrieve with javascript are strings. convert them to  integers with `parseInt()` function:

```
var qty = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
var price = parseInt($('#productPrice').val());
```

or

```
var total = parseInt(price) * parseInt(qty);
```

Also, change the type of your script to `text/javascript` instead of `text/jscript`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the jQuery library in your html.

Try the following

```
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

            <script type="text/jscript">

            $('#quantity').change(function(){
              var qty = $('#quantity').val();
              var price = $('#productPrice').val();
              var total = price * qty;
              $("#totalprice").val(total);
            });

            </script>
            </head>

            <body>




            <div class="pricesection">
                <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340"/>
            Quantity: 
            <select id="quantity">
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            Total: $
            <input type="text" id="totalprice" value="340"/>


            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </body>
```

The rest looks file to me.

Thanks,
Paras

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet

```js
$('#quantity').change(function() {
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  var price = $('#productPrice').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  $("#totalprice").val(total);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pricesection">
    <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340" />Quantity:
    <select id="quantity">
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    Total: $
    <input type="text" id="totalprice" value="340" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```